# Finding the recurrent formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Find the recurrent formula for: $a_{n+2}+4a_{n+1}+4a_n=0; a_0=1, a_1=3.$

I would probably want to calculate the first few elements in the sequence, however I fail right at the start. How can I calculate elements when there are $a_{n+2}, a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ and I only have two numbers $a_0$ and $a_1$ defined?

Thanks for any help

Comment: So, $a_2=-(4\cdot3+4\cdot1)$, e.g..

Comment: The method of characteristics works here.  The only complication is that $x^2+4x+4=0$ has a double root.

Comment: Are you just asking for:  $a_{n}=-4\times (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$?

Comment: @DavidMitra So $a_3 = 52 $?

Answer (score 1):

Since the characteristic roots are $-2,-2$ consider a linear combination of  $(-2)^n$ and $n(-2)^n$

Comment: Is the answer for the recurrent formula $-4*(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$?

Comment: The answer is for $a_{n+2}+4a_{n+1}+4a_n=0$

Comment: I just don't understand how does the characteristic equation $x^2+4x+4=0$ has a double root. It has a single root $-2$, right?

Comment: $(x+2)^2 =x^2+4x+4$